# How to write inline view in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

```
session.createQuery(" from " +
                "(select att.licenceNo license,driver.driverName drivername" +
                    " from DriverAttendanceDTO att,DriverDetailsDTO driver" +
                    " where att.licenceNo=driver.licenceNo" +
                    " and att.recordStatus='A'" +
                    " and driver.recordStatus='A' )");
```

Hibernate is giving me

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 7 [ from (select att.licenceNo license,driver.driverName drivername,att.present present from com.vms.dto.DriverAttendanceDTO att,com.vms.dto.DriverDetailsDTO driver where att.licenceNo=driver.licenceNo and att.recordStatus='A' and driver.recordStatus='A' )]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: My opinion is you are wasting your time with HQL. Just write a normal SQL query.

Comment: @david The above suggestion is not suitable.

Comment: @Kishan What is your objective ? And what does `from` suggest in the begining of the query ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `from (...)`:

```
session.createQuery("select att.licenceNo license,driver.driverName drivername" +
                    " from DriverAttendanceDTO att,DriverDetailsDTO driver" +
                    " where att.licenceNo=driver.licenceNo" +
                    " and att.recordStatus='A'" +
                    " and driver.recordStatus='A'");
```